# Batch Folder_Set in For as Variable

Tags: list, variables, for-loop, set, directory

What is wanted is the "folder_set", or "File_set" or folder/file lists part of a "For" command to be referred through a variable.
Suppose we wish to define a folder set in the "For /D" by:

```
SET "FOLDERSET=X* Y* Zee*"
```

and hope that something like

```
for %%B in (!FOLDERSET!) do (
```

will produce the miracle of iterating through the arrays as actual folders rather than just a string array.
It does appear to work when just using

```
SET "FOLDERSET=*"
```

or

```
SET "FOLDERSET=S*"
```

for folders beginning with "S" or

```
SET "FOLDERSET=S* G*"
```

again for folders beginning with "S" with G* not iterated, but the original problem remains to set up the appropriate delimiters for above wildcard list. Any way possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a more general solution for finding the first occurrence of a specified folder MYDIRFOUND in a specified folder set FOLDERSET in a specified drive range. Create a folder called MYDIRFOUND somewhere in a root folder of a name beginning with a letter in FOLDERSET:

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "FOLDERSET=ZZ* D* G* S* T*"


for %%T in (B C D F G) do (
if exist %%T: (

%%T:
cd \
for /D %%C in (!FOLDERSET!) do (

REM pushd popd won't upset the outer loop
pushd %%C

for /D /R %%K in (*) do (
REM MUST be (*) or will recurse for subfolders matching FOLDERSET. MYDIRFOUND is not one of them.

Set "MYTEMP=%%K"
SET "_MYDIR=!MYTEMP:MYDIRFOUND=!"

IF NOT !MYTEMP!==!_MYDIR! (
call SET "_MYDIR=%%~K"
goto MYDIRFOUND
)
)
popd
)

REM DRIVE LOOP AND EXIST
)
)
goto eof
:MYDIRFOUND
echo !_MYDIR!
echo success
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you are having a problem. It works perfectly fine for me, unless I don't understand your problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "folderset=s* x*"

echo Using normal expansion:
for /d %%F in (%folderset%) do @echo %%F
echo(

echo Using delayed expansion
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%F in (!folderset!) do @echo %%F
```

--OUTPUT--

```
Using normal expansion:
SETA
size
snake
svnsave
svntest
xml
xyz

Using delayed expansion
SETA
size
snake
svnsave
svntest
xml
xyz
```

There is a potential problem with delayed expansion in that %%F values containing `!` will be corrupted upon expansion if delayed expansion is enabled.